# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error because of possible erratum in book

Tags: python

I'm going through the new book "Data Science from Scratch: First Principles with Python" and I think I've found an errata.

When I run the code I get `"TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'".` I think this is because when I try to select `friend["friends"]`, `friend` is an integer that I can't subset. Is that correct? How can I continue the exercises so that I get the desired output? It should be a list of friend of friends (foaf). I know there's repetition problems but those are fixed later...

```
users = [
    {"id": 0, "name": "Ashley"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "Ben"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Conrad"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Doug"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Evin"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Florian"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Gerald"}
]

#create list of tuples where each tuple represents a friendships between ids
friendships = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,5), (1,2), (1,5), (2,3), (2,5), (3,4), (4,5), (4,6)]

#add friends key to each user 
for user in users:
    user["friends"] = []

#go through friendships and add each one to the friends key in users
for i, j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(j)
    users[j]["friends"].append(i)

def friends_of_friend_ids_bad(user): 
    #foaf is friend of friend
    return [foaf["id"]
        for friend in user["friends"]
        for foaf in friend["friends"]]

print friends_of_friend_ids_bad(users[0])
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 57, in <module>
    print friends_of_friend_ids_bad(users[0])
  File "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py", line 55, in friends_of_friend_ids_bad
    for foaf in friend["friends"]]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/marlon/Desktop/test.py"]
[dir: /Users/marlon/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

How I think it can be fixed:
I think you need users as a second argument and then do "for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]" instead of "for foaf in friend["friends"]

Comment: Post full traceback you got

Comment: what is `friendships` there ?

Comment: Well, what you get in friendships and stores on i and j must be an int (And ints, of course, don't have __ getitem __. Can you post the friendships code??

Comment: I missed it sorry. Added friendships code. @itzmeontv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've found an incorrect piece of code in the book.

Implementation for `friends_of_friend_ids_bad` function should be like this:

```
def friends_of_friend_ids_bad(user): 
    #foaf is friend of friend
    return [users[foaf]["id"]
        for friend in user["friends"]
        for foaf in users[friend]["friends"]]
```

`user["friends"]` is a list of integers, thus `friend` is an integer and `friend["friends"]` will raise `TypeError` exception

---

**UPD**

It seems, that the problem in the book was not about `friends_of_friend_ids_bad` function but about populating `friends` lists.

Replace

```
for i, j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(j)
    users[j]["friends"].append(i)
```

with

```
for i, j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(users[j])
    users[j]["friends"].append(users[i])
```

Then `friends_of_friend_ids_bad` and `friends_of_friend_ids` will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you that works! Did you read the book too? It is an errata then right?

Comment: @Do you know the correct code for friends_of_friend_ids(user) as well? Trying to figure it out but Counter is confusing me.

Comment: @user2469211 no. I think I can figure it out, but I have to read a few paragraphs first. I recommend you to post another question about `friends_of_friend_ids`

Comment: @user2469211 after reviewing your code I've updated my answer. Please read it. There is no need to modify `friends_of_friend_ids` and  `friends_of_friend_ids_bad` implementations.

Comment: Ok the code works when I do that but I don't understand it at all. When I look at the new dataset it look very odd with the friends column consisting of a list of dictionaries. Try it out. Know what I mean?

Comment: @user2469211 it adds users to `friends` lists instead of respective `id`s

Answer (score 0):

The error is on:

```
return [foaf["id"] for friend in user["friends"] for foaf in friend["friends"]]
```

In the second for loop, you're trying to access `__getitem__` of `users[0]["friends"]`, which is exactly 5 (ints don't have `__getitem__`).

You're trying to store on the list `foaf["id"]` for each friend in `user["friends"]` and for each foaf `friend["friends"]`. The problem is that foaf gets from `friend["friends"]` the number from a tuple inside friendships that was stored on users, and then you try to access `["id"]` from it, trying to call `__getitem__` from an integer value.

That's the exact cause of your problem.